# i want to use simba.spark.jdbc driver in sprint boot to connect to databricks with token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, databricks, azure-databricks, spring-jdbc

want to use  simba spark jdbc driver in spring boot to connect to data bricks with token
so that i can leverage the code over the "JDBC" boiler plate code and using row mapper and can fetch data from data bricks database , what will be user and password in case of connecting to data bricks
database using token as there is no user and password .and reference or code is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You just not need to set username & password explicitly - just provide URL. Here is a simple working example that uses Databricks SQL endpoint (full example is [here](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/spring-jdbc-dbsql)):

```
String host = "adb-123.11.azuredatabricks.net";
String httpPath = "/sql/1.0/endpoints/...";
String token = "your_token";
String query = "select count(1) from default.table";

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:spark://" + host + 
   ":443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=" +
   httpPath + ";AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=" + token;

SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
ds.setDriver(new Driver());
ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
int numRows = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, Integer.class);
```

Comment: hi alex, thanks for response .  i am getting timeout exception and not able to connect from application.properties i have add properties for spring.datasource.url,user,pass,driver etc ..any pointers

Comment: if you get timeout exception, check networking...